# If the function is not continuous at a certain point x=a, then why can you compute the limit via direct substitution?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

[image]

In the image attached, the function is not defined at x=7, so I am quite confused as to why my professor is able to (try) compute the limit via direct substitution (to get 0/0). I though that I am only able to use direct substitution to compute a limit IFF the function is continuous (and hence defined) at the point where you're trying to compute the limit at.

Comment: He means that the pair (numerator, denominator) satisfies one of the hypothesis of L'Hopital's theorem.

Comment: In this example, direct substitution fails -- it gives an indeterminate result.  This is precisely because the function is not continuous.  But since direct substitution gives a failure in the form $\frac {0}{0},$ L'Hopital's rule is a viable approach to evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 1):

That’s because after applying L’Hôpital’s theorem and differentiating nominator and denominator, we actually have a function that differs in the domain from the previous one. That is, we can now substitute $7$ without violating the domain, as we now won’t divide by $0$ anymore when evaluating at the point $x = 7$.